# How does whether a Pokemon is powered up before matter to find out its IV?

Tags: pokemon-go

When checking for a Pokemon's IV, there is a selection: is the Pokemon powered up before?

Why and how does it matter?

Is it true that because if we never powered it before, then the Pokemon can only be at level that is "not half level"?  That is, it can be only level 20, 21, 22, and so forth, and cannot be level 20.5?

So in that case, if in doubt, we can choose "it is powered before", because if we power it ourselves, then the level can be 20, 20.5, or anything, and therefore, be able to match for all possible results. Is that true?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer to your question is "Yes"

Comment: Your intuition is correct - acquired pokemon start at a whole level.  Hence, the option tries to be a shortcut in filtering out half level possibilities.  However, solving for IV stats from one data point usually has a wide range, so I do not see much advantage there.

Comment: right... unless if the Pokemon already has a CP of a larger number, such as 807 or 1638, then together with the "Strong", and "Best is Stamina, 13 to 14", then the chance of getting the real numbers is higher

Answer (score 3):

When you catch a wild Pokémon, the level of the Pokémon will always be a whole number between 1 and 30. Each time you power up a Pokémon, the level of the Pokémon increases by one half (0.5). Therefore, if a Pokémon has never been powered up, there's no point in checking half levels when checking IVs.

If you indicate that the Pokémon has been powered up, then half levels are also considered.

This can Be illustrated using the [IV Calculator](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator), on the [Poké Assistant](https://pokeassistant.com) website.

Marking the *Powered* field as *No*, results in only whole number levels being displayed in the results list.

> [image: Pokémon not powered]

However, if you change the *Powered* field to *Yes*, and calculate again. You'll see half levels included in the result set.

> [image: Pokémon powered]

Answer (score 1):

> The one other thing that goes into the calculation of IVs is whether or not you've ever powered up that Pokemon before. That's just because wild pokemons are always an odd level, so if you haven't powered them up before it can narrow down the possible sets of IVs significantly. credits /u/LastSasquatch

Extracted from reddit  [FAQ on IVs [Info Megathread]](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4tzcmk/faq_on_ivs_info_megathread/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: always an odd level? Maybe that is the non-half-level system... so in the half-level system, then it is "always a whole number (integer)"